# SQL query for active users

Tags: sql

This SQL query gives me today's number of users active in the last 30 days:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table.users
WHERE creation_tsz >= (now() - interval '30 days')
```

How can I modify it to get not a single value, but a table of active users for a range of dates?

My desired output would look like this:

```
Date       Users active in the last 30 days  
1/1/2010   10000  
1/2/2010   11234  
1/3/2010   12343  
1/4/2010   15944  
...        ...
```

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: When you say "active" users, please define what you mean by that. Are you using creation_tsz or is there another column to use for "active"?

Comment: I am using creation_tsz, but I want to get this value not only for today (which I do with the above query) but for a range of dates I set.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `COUNT(*)` with `*`.

Comment: The above exhausted my allowed memory size.

Comment: @Roberto: You can reduce the size of the output in two ways. Either limit the number of columns by replacing `count(*)` with `name, lastname, email, ...`.  Or reduce the time window, i.e. `interval '5 days'`

Comment: the interval must be 30 days, what I want to do is have a table output with two colums: a date (from a range I specify) and the number of users active in the 30 days leading to that date --maybe I wasn't clear.

Comment: @Roberto: For the date range, try `where creation_tsz between ('2010-01-01' - interval '30 days') and '2010-01-01'`.  Maybe you can post an example of the output you'd like to see.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what database you are using so it is hard to be specific. If there are no times in your dates, you can do this:

```
SELECT creation_tsz as Date, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM table.users
WHERE creation_tsz >= (now() - interval '30 days')
GROUP BY creation_tsz
```

Otherwise, this will get you pretty close to what you want (year excluded because you are only doing a 30 day range):

```
SELECT month(creation_tsz) as Month, day(creation_tsz) as Day, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM table.users
WHERE creation_tsz >= (now() - interval '30 days')
GROUP BY month(creation_tsz), day(creation_tsz)
```

Comment: how do I specify the start and end date of the date range for which I want the results?

Thanks

Comment: Try changing the where clause to: `where creation_tsz between '2010-01-01' and '2010-01-30'`

Answer (score 1):

If each data row in your table represents a distinct user, you can use the query below.

```
SELECT COUNT(1), date
FROM table
WHERE date >= (now() - interval '30 days')
GROUP BY 2 ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

If your table includes all sessions, but it has a distinct id per user, then you can use the query below.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT distinct_id), date
FROM table
WHERE date >= (now() - interval '30 days')
GROUP BY 2 ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```